# /bin/sh: install: not found

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, binary

I have copied `install` binary to AMR based target to `/usr/bin` directory with execute permission. While trying to run the binary, it throws an error "/bin/sh: install: not found"

I checked the PATH variable also.

```
> echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I tried copying binary file to `/bin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` dirs also with no luck.

What is going wrong to run this binary?

Comment: Have you given the binary permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have given that

Comment: Can you run it locally succesfully?

Comment: I can't even run it locally from the directory where it is copied.

Comment: Have you tried running it like ./install?